# dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket: Address already in use

Tags: networking, dnsmasq, tftp

The OS is Scientific Linux 6.3 (which is similar to redhat, centos and fedora) and I have installed dnsmasq with the following configuration

```
interface=eth1
domain=hpclab
expand-hosts
dhcp-range=10.0.2.51,10.0.2.100,static
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
dhcp-host=08:00:27:69:73:7A,ws04,10.0.2.51
```

and current node (which runs dnsmasq) has this ip

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A9:20:C0  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea9:20c0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

However, I get error when trying to start the dnsmasq service

```
[root@localhost mahmood]# /etc/init.d/dnsmasq status
dnsmasq is stopped
[root@localhost mahmood]# /etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
Starting dnsmasq: 
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket: Address already in use
                                                       [FAILED]
```

netstat command shows the following information

```
[root@localhost mahmood]# netstat -anlp | grep -w LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1252/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1445/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1685/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46556               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1348/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1252/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      4884/httpd          
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      1445/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 :::51096                    :::*                        LISTEN      1348/rpc.statd
```

and

```
[root@localhost mahmood]# netstat -aunp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69                  0.0.0.0:*                               5110/xinetd         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34136               0.0.0.0:*                               1323/avahi-daemon   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38756               0.0.0.0:*                               1348/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353                0.0.0.0:*                               1323/avahi-daemon   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1003                0.0.0.0:*                               1252/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               1252/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               1445/cupsd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:676                 0.0.0.0:*                               1348/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               5189/dhclient       
udp        0      0 :::1003                     :::*                                    1252/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    1252/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 :::43248                    :::*                                    1348/rpc.statd
```

What can cause such error and how can I fix that?

Comment: Please also post the output of `netstat -anup`. My guess is that there is some process bound to UDP/53 and/or UDP/67.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you have configured `dnsmasq` to provide TFTP service (via the `enable-tftp` option in `dnsmasq.conf`). The service port for TFTP is UDP/69, so `dnsmasq` wants to bind to it, but `xinetd` has already done so, and it is impossible for two different processes to bind to the same service port.

If you want `dnsmasq` to provide TFTP service, you will need to edit the `xinetd` configuration (likely `/etc/xinetd.conf`) to turn off its TFTP service. Or, if you prefer to have `xinetd` provide TFTP service, then you will need to remove `enable-tftp` from `dnsmasq.conf`.

Comment: what did not help me was that the errror _dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.2.1: Address already in use_ is possibly a bit mis-leading with its "Address already in use" as it is actually the port already in use

but applying similar logic to this answer `netstat -anup` pointed me to `in.tftp` which i stopped with `service tftpd-hpa stop`